# Is XML to android as HTML is to websites?

Tags: javascript, java, android, html, xml

I answered a very general question on another website recently where I said:
application development involves
Layout, styling and logic.

In web html is for layout. Desktop (windows) XAML and android XML.

I was being simplistic about it because it was a very simple question. Somebody replied that that is not the case stating that:

HTML

```
<button id=”button”>Button</button>

var button = document.getElementById(“button”);
```

JAVA

```
<Button android:id="@+id/my_button" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" …

Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
```

Are not equivalents.

At first I thought that there were surely technical differences. However as an analogy the more I think about it is the more it holds up.

The browser reads the html and constructs the DOM. When the javascript is executed it can get a reference to elements in the DOM by requesting it.

It seems to me that the same thing is happening in the java.
The compiler or whatever reads the XML and builds out the layout. in order for the codebehind to refer to to the UI element that was created from the XML it must search for it by id.

I see the same sort of thing in swift, and XAML.

**What are the practical differences between the two pieces of code?
What are the theoretical differences?**

I am learning and I just want to understand if my reasoning is incorrect and how to improve it. I think they might be different in terms of their what is happening at a low level. But at a higher level they are effectively the same.

Comment: *"In web html is for layout. Desktop (windows) XAML and android XML"* No. XML is a general format for data. *Any* kind of data. XAML is XML. HTML can be XML. So saying that XML is layout for Android is wrong. --- Besides, it's CSS that's "layout" for the web, not HTML.

Comment: Ok. What would be a better way to express what I am thinking? I accept that  XML is a general format for data. I can't figure out a better way to express the idea that you describe/define the layout for android layouts in XML.